# VC++ vector iterator initialization

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, vector

I have the following deceleration in my header file

```
// 3D Vector
typedef struct tagV3D /*: V2D*/ {
  union {
   struct {
          double x;
          double y;
          double z;
   };
   struct {
          struct tagV2D v2d_;
   };
 };
} V3D, TVec3D, *PVec3D;
```

now i have a method inside my cpp file

```
    bool InsertSelfIntersectionVertexes(vector<PVec3D> &avtxlst) {

    PVec3D vtx;
    int iI;
    ...

    vtx = new TVec3D;
    *vtx = v;
    PVec3D* p= avtxlst.begin() + iI + 1;
    avtxlst.insert(p, vtx);

    ...
    }
```

I get following errors trying to compile the code

`error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' to 'PVec3D *'`
and
`error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> std::vector<_Ty>::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>,const _Ty &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PVec3D' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'`

How do I Fix this?

The following code worked fine with **vc6** and the errors appeared when migrated to **VS 2008**.
Why is that ?
Appreciate any answers

Comment: Why is *PVec3D not PVec3D, that is without the star?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `vector<T>::iterator` is a type by itself and is not compatible with your pointer to your struct.  You should create a `vector<PVec3D>::iterator my_iter = avtxlst.begin()`.

Now you can do the same operations on your iterator, as you can with the pointer you had.  Such as increment, `my_iter++` or dereference `*my_iter`.

You can then use `my_iter` and increment it by `Ii` and whatever else you need to do.