# cannot convert parameter

Tags: c++

I have this that compiles fine in VC++ 6.0

```
typedef std::vector<ILBCOM_FieldStruct*> FieldsVector;
FieldsVector m_coll;
FieldsVector::iterator it(&m_coll[Index-1]);
m_coll.erase(it);
```

I need to compile in Visual Studio C++ 2010

The error message is on the 3rd line:

> error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>::_Vector_iterator(const
>   std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'ILBCOM_FieldStruct **' to 'const std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> &'

Do you see something wrong?

Comment: Try having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848875/vc-vector-iterator-initialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` does not have a constructor that converts from `T*`. It *does* have a copy constructor:

```
FieldsVector::iterator it(m_coll.begin()+Index-1);
```

Comment: To be clear, in VC++6, `std::vector<T>::iterator` was simply `T*`; since then, it's a proper iterator class instead.